# A card is drawn from standard deck of playing cards. What is the probability that it is a)a face and heart card b) face or heart card

Tags: probability

I am quite confused about b) part. Whether to use $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$
Assuming P(A) is the probability of face and P(B) is the probability of heart

or just face probability is $12/52$ and heart probability is $13/52$.
So = $(12/52)+(13/52)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible to have both a face card and a card of hearts at the same time? (Hint - Yes)

So your method of adding $12/52$ and $13/52$ is double counting all the cards that are both a heart and a face, so you need to subtract off this double counting.

Hence, you will use $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

Comment: Could you also answer A part question as well

Comment: There are only $3$ face cards with hearts: jack of hearts, queen of hearts, and king of hearts. Thus there is a probability of $3/52$ of picking a card that is a heart and a face card